# How do I alter incoming params to make them meet Rails' strong params requirement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good sirs.

I'm trying to add a JSON API to a todo list.

The specs suggest that this command should create a new user.

```
curl -d 'username=third&password=thirdpassword' http://localhost:3000/api/users/
```

But since I'm using Rails 4, I have this requirement which wants my params nested inside `:new_user`.

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:new_user).permit(:username, :password)
  end
```

The first thing I tried was this...

```
  def user_params
    params = { :new_user => params }
    params.require(:new_user).permit(:username, :password)
  end
```

...which worked nicely in the console, but in my app it only complained about no implicit conversion of symbol to string. Changing `:new_user` to a string didn't help either.

What is the correct way to deal with this problem - assuming I stick with Rails 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this

```
 def user_params
    params.permit(:username, :password)
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. Just found out I wasn't required to match the nested params so that makes everything nice and easy